# If statement not working on space bar count

Tags: javascript

So I built a counter but I didn't manage to implement if statements.

Ex:

```
if (hits == 1) {alert("hello world1")}
if (hits == 2) {alert("hello world2")}
if (hits == 3) {alert("hello world3")}
if (hits == 4) {alert("hello world4")}
```

This is my code

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <p id="hits" value="0"> </p>

    <script>
      var hits = 0;
      var hitElement = document.getElementById("hits");
      document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {addHit()}
      }
      var addHit = function() {hits++; renderHits()}
      var renderHits = function() {hitElement.innerHTML = hits % 5}
      var resetHits = function() {renderHits()}
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Also I was wondering if is it possible to make it work based on .value instead of .innerHTML (because my objective is that the space counter works "behind the scenes", so it should not be visible).

Thanks!

Comment: `.value` would only work if `p` was an `input` tag. If you insist on using `p` you can use `.textContent` which will save time by not checking the update html elements etc.

Comment: No I do not care if it works on p and nor do I care if it is displayed I only would like that it works if I implement if statements (actually my objective is to switch between images pressing enter bar, so if I go like "if (value == 2) {document.getElementById("image").src = "something.png"}"

Comment: Where do you load the if statements in your script?

Comment: `if (e.keyCode == 32) { addHit(); doSomething(); }` + `function doSomething() { switch (hits) { case 1: ...; break; case 2: ...; break; ... } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*actually my objective is to switch between images pressing enter bar*

```js
let hits = 0;
const hitElement = document.getElementById("hits");

const images = [
    "https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=qwe", // your 1 image
    "https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=rty", // your 2 image
    "https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=uyi", // your 3 image
    "https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=opd", // your 4 image
    "https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=asd", // your 5 image
];

document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
        hits++;
        hitElement.src = images[hits % images.length];
    }
};
```

```html
<p>Press spacebar</p>
<img id="hits" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=qwe" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <body>
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
    <p id="hits" value="0"> 0</p>

 <script>
 var hits = 0;
 var hitElement = document.getElementById("hits");
 document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 32) {addHit()}}
 var addHit = function() {hits++; renderHits()}
 var renderHits = function() {hitElement.innerText = hits % 5}
  var resetHits = function() {renderHits()}
```

Comment: Now try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Its the "hits % 5" thing. Interpreter sees it as ((lresult = a) % b) rather than (lresult=(a % b)).

Needs parenthesis.

```js
let hits = 0;
const hitElement = document.getElementById("hits");

document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
        hits++;
        hitElement.src = `https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=${(hits % 5)  + 1}`;
    }
};
```

```html
<p>Press spacebar</p>
<img id="hits" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=1"></ing>
```